# How to create a masked email system?

Tags: email, smtp

I would like to implement a system of email masking on my web site/server similar to those ones of some ads' websites.

Example scenario: mysite.com

```
1) Bob posts an ad with ID #1234
2) Alice is interested and she contacts him through the website control panel
3) Bob receives an email from a-1234@mysite.com to his email bob@bob.com
4) Bob answers to a-1234@mysite.com, my web server receive the email and forwards it to alice@alice.com
5) Alice receives the email to her email alice@alice.com from b-1234@mysite.com
6) Alice answers to b-1234@mysite.com, my web server receive the email and forwards it to bob@bob.com
7) ...and so on
```

How can do that?

Thank you